# core_email_queue_send_all - not beig queued

Tags: email, cron, magento1.9.3

I'm dealing problems with order confirmation emails in my website. I'm using SMTP pro and have set custom smtp method to send emails. It works fine if I choose to send these emails immidiatelly. If I choose to queue these emails and send them via cron job, it's not working.

I noticed that "core_email_queue_send_all" is stuck in running proccess, never finishes execution, causing all other crons to get stuck as well. (displays Runtime:-419985h -5m -4s). I tried deleting all crons queued but as soon as "core_email_queue_send_all" is starting to run, it gets stuck again etc. etc.

Any ideas of what may be the cause of this issue?

Comment: check va/log folder

Comment: @SunilPatel there are som warnings/notices in system.log, but not related to emails